# Session doesn't work after upgrade to Play Framework 2.5.4, Scala

Tags: scala, session, playframework, playframework-2.0

After upgrading my project to Play Framework 2.5.4 from 2.4.8, I'm having issue while working with session. There are to methods in my controller to test the issue:

```
def test = Action { implicit request =>
  Redirect(controllers.routes.Carts.test2()).withSession(new Session(Map("user" -> "customer")))
}

def test2 = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(request.session.data.toString())
}
```

Basically `test` method adds session and redirects to `test2` method. When I open page with test method url after redirect I'm getting what I need in the browser:

> Map(user -> customer)

But if I refresh page after that I'm getting:

> Map(csrfToken ->
>     ce1a6222484f378d38ab3534c2b400191270395d-1470238791014-c988ce3fe47259173166949a)

So, seems like session works for one request only and then overwrites with csrfToken. I have disabled all the filters. My class with filters looks like this:

```
class Filters @Inject() () extends HttpFilters {
  val filters = Seq.empty
}
```

Can't understand what is wrong with my code. The same code was working fine before upgrade.

Comment: Are you refreshing at the browser without doing the redirect again?

Comment: @marcospereira Yes, just refreshing at the browser

Comment: can u show ur configuration (application.conf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in ur application.conf if  session.secure is true bring it to

```
play.http.session.secure=false
```